# Oracle connectivity with NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm

I am trying to connect oracle with NodeJS. Steps followed as below. Pre - requisites there is no client installed except NodeJS(0.10.25) and npm(1.3.24).

In my ExpressJS Project:

- npm install db-oracle
  There is no error found while installing.
- In app.js

  ```
  var oracle = require('db-oracle');
  var connString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)))";
  var connectData = { "tns": connString, "user": "XPPS_OWNER", "password": "Ex3ec" };
  ```
- In one of the endpoint i coded like this,

  ```
  app.get('/oracleendpoint',function(req,res){
  connectData.connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log("CONNECTION ERROR: " + error);
    }

  this.query().select('*').from('Users').execute(function(error, rows) {
      if (error) {
          return console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
      }
      console.log(rows.length + ' ROWS');
     });
  });
  });
  ```

Expected output is to connect the DB.

FYI: DB Instance is running fine.

Query:

- What is the DB Name?
- It is showing an error which show below. what would be root cause for this?

  ```
  module.js:340
  throw err;
      ^
  Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/oracle_bindings'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> 
  (C:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\node_modules\db-oracle\db-oracle.js:18:15)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  ```

Please let me know any missing or Installation required or any node modules required or code changes. I have Googled but in vain. Haven't found proper document for this error.

Comment: Is there a file `oracle_bindings` in the mentioned folder? Did you follow the description from the package? https://www.npmjs.org/package/db-oracle

Comment: There is no file called oracle_bindings and I didnt followed the instructions due to i am working on windows system and my requirement is just need to connect the database. Even oracle is not installed in my local system. It was in remote system.

Comment: I'm sorry, but connecting to an Oracle database is a massive undertaking (no irony here) and will _never_ be possible without having at least the oracle client libraries on your machine installed. Furthermore I don't think that this library will even compile on a windows system, maybe have a look at [node-oracle](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle themselves have just released an Oracle driver for node.js: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/introducing_node_oracledb_a_node

Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you use `db-oracle` module, I would recommend to use [node-oracle](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle) module instead, as it is more popular/better maintained.

To connect to Oracle DB from Node, you have to follow the instructions on the page mentioned above.